# How can I reference the original of a currently edited commit during git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I would like to get some information about the original of the currently edited commit during a `git rebase -i` but HEAD references a different commit hash. How can I reference the original commit?

### Example:

```
$ git rebase -i upstream
```

(Choose "edit" for a commit)

```
[detached HEAD befa32f] Previous commit message
 1 file changed, 121 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 rewrite README.md (100%)
Stopped at 9a1e25391e5a53965c80dc69e1285dba7c59f893... Current commit message
You can amend the commit now, with

        git commit --amend

Once you are satisfied with your changes, run

        git rebase --continue
```

Now I would like to reference `9a1e25391e5a53965c80dc69e1285dba7c59f893` but HEAD has a different hash and different properties, although it seems to be the same commit:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
1414539371fe6b122d5f326bc7b344eea761dc50
```

Where does this come from and how can I reference the original commit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "currently edited commit" or "upstream commit"...

Comment: For what it's worth, `HEAD` is *always* the *current* commit, by definition.  The `HEAD` file either contains a reference to a branch name (the usual case of being on a branch) or a raw SHA-1 ("detached HEAD" mode).  During an `edit` phase of a `git rebase -i` you are in "detached HEAD" mode.

Comment: @torek that's how I would have expected it too but somehow I got different results. Then it might have been my mistake, will try again with HEAD next time. Thanks!

Comment: @torek please post an answer that can be accepted so other people passing through don't think the question is unanswered.

Comment: @lassombra: hm, I can do that but the real problem is that the question itself is kind of malformed (in that we don't know what the OP was looking at and how he got into whatever state he was in).  I'll write up something though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, by definition `HEAD` is *always* the "current commit"—or perhaps it would be more accurate to say "the current commit is whatever `HEAD` says it is".

At most "normal" times, `HEAD` contains a reference to a branch name: if you `cat .git/HEAD` for instance (or open it in a file viewer or your editor) you'll see `ref: refs/heads/master`, or `ref: refs/heads/develop`, depending on what branch you're on.  In this case you're on the named branch, and the current commit is the tip of that branch.<sup>1</sup>

If you use `git checkout --detach` or give `git checkout` a raw commit SHA-1, on the other hand, git puts you into "detached HEAD" mode.  While this sounds like a scene from the 18th century French Revolution, it just means that `HEAD` refers directly to a raw SHA-1.  In this case, that SHA-1 is the current commit.

When you run `git rebase -i` and have it stop on a commit (by setting the disposition to `edit`), the rebase leaves you in "detached HEAD" mode, with the current commit—a.k.a. `HEAD`—being the commit that you are now able to edit.  You can, at this point, make some changes to the tree and do a `git add`, for instance: the changes you make to the tree and then `add` are now in the staging area.  If the next thing you do is `git commit --amend`, git makes a new commit whose parent is the same as the current commit's parent:

```
       old   <-- HEAD before `git commit --amend`
      /
...--o
      \
       new   <-- HEAD after `git commit --amend`
```

Note that after the `git commit --amend`, `HEAD` is still "the current commit" (by definition), it's just no longer the commit you were going to change (`old` above).

There's no one right way to refer to the SHA-1 of `old` by name, at this point, but there are several ways to find it: `git log --graph --decorate --oneline HEAD ORIG_HEAD`, for instance, will show commits reachable from both `HEAD` (where you are now, on commit `new`) and `ORIG_HEAD` (which records where you were when you first started the rebase: this is not necessarily commit `old` but it will have commit `old` in its history).

For instance, while stopped in a `rebase -i HEAD~2` I added a new file and committed this with `git commit --amend`, resulting in this:

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline HEAD ORIG_HEAD
* 9daa414 (HEAD) mod1, amended
| * bd49ea7 (master) mod2
| * f071da2 mod1
|/  
* 28c4ee8 initial
```

Or you can depend on git internals (which have changed over time so there's no guarantee that this will work for you):

```
$ ls .git/rebase-merge
amend                   git-rebase-todo.backup  onto
author-script           head-name               orig-head
done                    interactive             patch
end                     message                 quiet
git-rebase-todo         msgnum                  stopped-sha
```

Here, `rebase-merge/stopped-sha` has the SHA-1 of the commit that was current at the time I stopped for editing, so:

```
$ git rev-parse rebase-merge/stopped-sha
f071da26a90f14945d89ccdeed3c278e9b499a2e
```

As [Joseph K. Strauss noted in the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267344/how-can-i-reference-the-current-commit-during-git-rebase/28271026#comment44897606_28271026), probably the simplest way to find `old` is to use git's reflogs.  Since we just now created commit `new` and moved `HEAD`, the old commit `old`'s SHA-1 is simply `HEAD@{1}`.  Of course if you make several commits (e.g., several `--amend`s trying to get it just perfect),<sup>2</sup> `old` may be under `HEAD{2}`, `HEAD@{3}`, or higher.

Note that at this point, when I do `git rebase --continue`, what git does is apply the remaining items (which are in `rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` in the above `ls` output) to the current `HEAD`.  If all goes well, the last thing `rebase` does is re-point the then-current branch (in `rebase-merge/head-name`, which in this case contains `refs/heads/master`) to the tip-most commit it just made, and then restore the indirect reference status of `HEAD`, so that I'm now on the new tip of branch `master`:

```
$ git rebase --continue
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Or, as a special case, if `HEAD` contains a reference to a branch but the branch does not exist yet, you're said to be on an "unborn branch".  In this case there is *no* current commit, but when you make a new commit it will be the initial commit on the new, now-born, branch.  Typically people only see this when creating the first commit in a new repository, after `git init`.  In git version 1.7.2 and later, however, using `git checkout --orphan <branchname>` creates a new unborn branch, so that you can make a new history unconnected to existing history in an existing repository.

<sup>2</sup>I can't speak for anyone else but I do this *all the time*. :-)

Comment: You could always use `HEAD@{1}` for the previous state of `HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped understanding what's going on. I wasn't aware that amend creates a new commit and had come to the wrong conclusions.